# Why is CriteriaBuilder creating a malformed query for "in" CollectionTable?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

When attempting to generate dynamic queries using `CriteriaBuilder`, Hibernate is not creating the proper SQL with regards to an Entities member variable associated with `@ElementCollection`.

Sample Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myclass")
public class MyClass {
...
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "myclass_mysubclass",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myclass_id")
    )
    @Column(name = "mysubclass_id")
    private List<Integer> mySubClassIDs;
...
}
```

CriteriaBuilder code:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyClass.class);
Expression<Object> e = root.get("mySubClassIDs");
List<Object> o = (List<Object>) entry.getValue();
criteriaQuery.where(e.in(o));
```

where `entry.getValue()` will return an `ArrayList<Integer>` of [1]

Produces:

```
SELECT distinct count(myclass0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
FROM hotel myclass0_ 
cross join myclass_mysubclass mySubClassids1_ 
where myclass0_.id=mySubClassids1_.myclass_id and (. in (1))
```

Why is Hibernate not generating the "in" clause properly?  the "." should be mySubClassids1_.mysubclass_id

Am I missing something in the annotation of the member variable? Doesn't seem so, as it is enough to generate the cross join.

The env is Jboss AS 7 with Hibernate 4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3 on jdk-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is creating two separate tables:

```
create table myclass (
    id int8 not null,
    primary key (id)
);
create table myclass_mysubclass (
    myclass_id int8 not null,
    mysubclass_id int4
);
```

So, it seems you need to do a join instead of a get:

```
Expression<Object> e = root.join("mySubClassIDs");
```

Worked for me at any rate.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! however join cannot be used in this particular case for various reasons.  As shown above, the join is created, it's just the expression of "in" does not create the proper left hand operand.  It just has "." and doesn't specify the table nor column, even though it is aware of the join table as it created the cross join.

Comment: Nicholas, I've heeded your advice and went with explicitly using Join.  The code will look a bit ugly as reflection will be used to determine the class type of member variables and then deciding via if statements to build the appropriate Expression, but I digress :)

Comment: Sounds a bit like a design issue, but I'm glad you made progress.